# PyQt5 - Separating program into two classes

Tags: python, oop, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using stackedWidget to run app which can switch between multiple pages, the following code works except i need the cryp() and other functions it requires to run to be put into another class or better yet separate file

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *#QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtGui, uic
import unicodedata

from ui_mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_win=QMainWindow()
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.main_win)    
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.home)
        
        self.ui.adfgvx.clicked.connect(self.gotoAdf)
        self.ui.affine.clicked.connect(self.gotoAffine)
        
        self.ui.buttonSpocitejSoucetDvou.clicked.connect(self.cryp)
        self.ui.buttonSpocitejSoucetTri.clicked.connect(self.decryp)
        self.ui.comboBox.currentText()
        self.ui.lineEditHodnotaC.text()
        

    def show(self):
        self.main_win.show()
        
    def gotoAdf(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page)
            
    def gotoAffine(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.pageAffine)   
    

    '''
class affine(MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_win=QMainWindow()
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.main_win)    
        
        self.ui.buttonSpocitejSoucetDvou.clicked.connect(self.cryp)
        self.ui.buttonSpocitejSoucetTri.clicked.connect(self.decryp)
        self.ui.comboBox.currentText()
        self.ui.lineEditHodnotaC.text()
    '''

    def chckinput(self):
        ...

    def errmsg(self,message): 
        ...
        
    def strip_accents(self,text):
        ...


    def makec(self): #####upravi text mezery balast co jde do encrypt
        ...
    
    def makeb(self):############ taky upravuje ale decrypt
        ...
    
    def cryp(self):

        a=int(self.ui.comboBox.currentText())
        b=self.chckinput() 
        m=37
        chars = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"
                 ,"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"," "]
        res=[]
        char =self.makec()
        for i in range(len(char)):        
            d=chars.index(char[i])
            vzorec=((a*d+b)%m)
            res.append(chars[vzorec]) 
            encryptedText=''.join(res)
        if len(encryptedText)>4: #osetreni rozdeleni na petice
            fives=' '.join(encryptedText[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(encryptedText), 5))
            return (self.ui.labelSoucetDvou.setText(fives),
                    self.ui.lineEditHodnotaB.clear(), ##vrati automaticky hodnotu do pole 2
                    self.ui.lineEditHodnotaB.setText(''.join(res)))
        else:
            return (self.ui.labelSoucetDvou.setText(''.join(res)),
                    self.ui.lineEditHodnotaB.clear(),
                    self.ui.lineEditHodnotaB.setText(''.join(res)))
```

uncommenting the affine class results in attribute errors related to any widget, label or button operation happening in cryp()

Comment: If `affine` is another page and you want to use a separate class for that, you need to move that page to a *separate* widget in Designer, remove it from your main window, replace it with an empty widget and use widget promotion for that other class (do some research on the topic to find out how it works). Note: classes should have capitalized names.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you, I've ended up deleting the widgets from main window and instead making them as separate new forms loading each ui in its file and linking them back to main with addWidget. Seems to be working fine for my use case.